# undefined method `id' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can't get id value from a model.

My code:

```
session["game_space"]   = params[:game_space_id]

@player_space = PlayerSpace.where(game_space_id: session["game_space"], user_id: current_user.id)

session["player_space"] = @player_space.id #<<<<===== The error occurs here

redirect_to "show",:id => @player_space.id
```

Error message:

```
Error: undefined method `id' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

Can you help me on this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Problems:

- Where clause returns active record relation object which is a kind of array (collection). So you have to pick the object to call the id method over it.

  @player_space = PlayerSpace.where(game_space_id: session["game_space"], user_id: current_user.id).first
- Your query results/collection doesn't have any row/object. So calling `#first` will return nil. So as a result `nil#id` will cause error again.

Hope you get the point!

Comment: If you expect to get one record, it's also acceptable to forgo the where and do find_by

Comment: If you expect to get one record, it's also acceptable to forgo the where and do find_by: `PlayerSpace.find_by(game_space_id: session[:game_space], user_id: current_user.id)`

Comment: I did not use .first because I have only one row. Now, I put first and the error still occurs. Note: if I try: session["player_space"] = @player_space.name works. So, I hope I can not access the id... I really do not know.

Comment: Whatever rows you have dear, where clause is designed to return kind of collection object. So eighter it will return emply collection/array or it will return on result in the collection but not as a single record! The #id method is callable here on the record. Its the column of your desired table. So when the expected output is empty or nil. It can't be called.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to get an `id` on an ActiveRecord Relation.  Try this:

`@player_space = PlayerSpace.where(game_space_id: session["game_space"], user_id: current_user.id).first`

Then get the id of `@player_space`

Answer (score 2):

You're getting an `ActiveRecord::Relation` class back, not a model object. You could get the id from an item in the relation. If you're certain that you're going to get exactly one item back, you could simply do:

```
PlayerSpace.where(game_space_id: session["game_space"], user_id: current_user.id).first
```