# Failed to get RoR Active Record model id to execute a query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, activerecord, orm

I'm working on rails project with ActiveRecord. I'm doing some step-by-step querying and it seems that I'm missing key concepts since I'm new to Activerecord. I'm not able to get id on model and as a result to execute a query. Here's my code:

```
questions = JSON.parse(q)
selected_answers = questions.map do |ques|
  ques['options'].map do |opt|
     Answer.where(value: opt['title'])
  end
end

participants = selected_answers.flatten!.map do |sa|
  Participant.where(answers: sa.id)
end

stats[:answers] = participants.map do |p|
  Answer.where(participants: p.id) #this line causes an error
end
```

I get error

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `id' for #<Participant::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fc478423bc0>):
  app/services/survey_statistics.rb:143:in `block in get_question'
  app/services/survey_statistics.rb:142:in `map'
  app/services/survey_statistics.rb:142:in `get_question'
  app/services/survey_statistics.rb:25:in `block in questions'
  app/services/survey_statistics.rb:22:in `questions'
  app/controllers/api/v1/reports_controller.rb:13:in `questions'
```

Comment: It looks like your variable 'participants' is a collection of collections. This link might help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27021036/undefined-method-id-for-activerecordrelation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Pholochtairze's answer is spot on.  This answer is to remove all those calls to map and to efficiently get all the answers you need (pun intended :p)

first you get the list of selected answers.  We're going to save all titles to a different variable and use that to get all the answers.  We also will use [`flat_map`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/flat_map) for the outermost loop.

```
questions = JSON.parse(q)

titles = questions.flat_map do |ques|
  ques['options'].map { |opt| opt['title'] }
end

selected_answers = Answer.where(value: titles)
```

One issue with `flatten!` and other `!` methods is that they return nil when there is no change made because you don't normally want to use them in chains.  So the big refactor here is to move the call to `map` inside the `where` method.

```
participants = Participant.where(answers: selected_answers.map(&:id))
```

A better refactor is to use [`pluck`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck) instead of `map` since `selected_answers` is now an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object.  This will prevent Rails from creating the records unnecessarily.

```
participants = Participant.where(answers: selected_answers.pluck(:id))
```

For the final part, we want to get the answers for the participants we got earlier.  You can still use `map` but again, we'll use `pluck` for efficiency.

```
stats[:answers] = Answer.where(participants: participants.pluck(:id))
```

And there you have it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `participants` is a collection of collections. You are using `map` so your variable `p` is now a collection (actually `Participant::ActiveRecord_Relation` tells you it's a collection), that's why it has no `id`. I would try to loop again through the collection (the `p` one this time) as follows :

```
stats[:answers] = participants.map do |p|
  p.map do |p1|
    Answer.where(participants: p1.id)
  end
end
```

You can find a related problem here : [undefined method `id' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27021036/undefined-method-id-for-activerecordrelation)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because you did **map** which constructs an array combining with **where** which also returns an array, so you have array of arrays:

```
stats[:answers] = participants.map do |p|
  Answer.where(participants: p.id) #this line causes an error
end
```

You can achieve your goals much simpler, as far as I understood your business logic you can substitute all your code with this:

```
questions = JSON.parse(q)
titles = questions.each_with_object([]) do |q, a| 
  q["options"].each { |option| a << option["title"] }
end

participants_ids = Answer.where(value: titles).pluck(:participant_id)
stats[:answers] = Answer.where(participant_id: participant_ids)
```